# Custom query var in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to give a pretty url to my custom CPT (Orders). This is the way im trying:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_type_link', 1, 3);
function custom_post_type_link( $link, $post = 0 ){
    if ( $post->post_type == 'orders' ){
            $order_code = 1121000+$post->ID;
      return home_url( 'orders/' .  $order_code);
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}
```

Assume that post ID is 32, This code creates the following url:
http://www.example.com/orders/1121032

Now i wanna write a code to display the post with post ID=32 in above url.
I heard somewhere that i should use custom query vars. But i don't know how to use it.
This is the rest of code i've written

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_add_query_vars');
function custom_add_query_vars($qVars){
$qVars[] = "code";
return $qVars;
}

 add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrites_init' );
    function custom_rewrites_init(){
        add_rewrite_rule(
            'orders/([0-9]+)?$',
            'index.php?post_type=orders&code=$matches[1]',
            'top' );
    }
```

Comment: You can't, since you are adding 1121000 to the post ID within the link. The rewrite would need to subtract from the match.

Comment: @George is there a way to subtract 1121000 from the match?

Comment: Not with a rewrite AFAIK. Why are you adding that value to the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding custom rewrite rules, wordpress needs to be told to activate the new rule.

Use this method after the `add_rewrite_rule` function call.

```
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

Warning: `flush_rules` is expensive, you definitely don't want to call it on every request. Typically you would put the `custom_rewrites_init` and `flush_rules` in a plugin [register_activation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) function.

If you're lazy, you can just add it to your code once, make a request to the website (which will rewrite the .htaccess rewrite rules), then comment the `flush_rules` method out.